# CSS3 font-face is not working for select box options, IE

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using the font-face attribute for select box, when i scroll the select box the font won't be. and when i select it, then it will be displayed..

what is the problem behind this

thanks

**My code:**

**CSS:**

```
<style>
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Rupee Foradian';
    src: url('rupee/Rupee_Foradian.eot');
    src: local('Rupee Foradian'), url('rupee/Rupee_Foradian.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('rupee/Rupee_Foradian.woff') format('woff'),
    url('rupee/Rupee_Foradian.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
#minprice{
    font-family:'Rupee Foradian';
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="minprice" id="minprice">
<option value=""> No min</option>
<option value="2000000">`  20 Lakhs</option>
<option value="2500000">`  25 Lakhs</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, Added example code

Answer (score 0):

the raw select box has many problems in browsers, so if you want more custom style, you may simulate a select box via div or span etc.